# Using Interface in java

Tags: java

I want to implement the `Myinterface` interface in both the classes i.e, `OracleImp` and `SQLImp` . But I am getting an error

> 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at Hello.main(Hello.java:34)'**

Here is my code

```
interface MyInterface{
    void connect();
}


class OracleImp implements MyInterface{

    public void connect(){
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to oracle server");
    }
 }

 class SQLImp implements MyInterface{

     public void connect(){
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to SQL server");
     }
 }


public class Hello{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
        MyInterface obj = (MyInterface)c.newInstance();
        obj.connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing command line arguments while running your `Hello` class?

Comment: did you send any value using jvm arguments while running the application

Comment: @Simze, obviously not :)

Comment: No i am not passing any CLA while running Hello class  @Simze

Comment: Yes, that's why voted to close as "problem no longer can be reproduced or simple typographical error" @kocko

Comment: @naveenadhikari then it's obvious you except exception, without passing arguments you're trying to read 0th element which does not exist

Comment: @simze I didn't get you. Actually I am new to Java and OOP I was just trying out an example from a book. And, I assumed that the example would work and I am not able to figure why it doesn't work.

Comment: What should i do to make my code work?

Answer (score 0):

Before you use `Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);`, you need have a check to ensure the `args[0]` is not empty.
Like that :

```
if(args.length<1){
 System.exit(0);
}
else{
Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
...
}
```

Comment: @王劲涛- Wouldn't **args[0]** have the name of the classes (OracleImp,SQLImp) as string values.??

Comment: Hey Guys thanks for bearing with me. the problem has been solved and now in retrospect i know how silly the question was. :D. But still I am glad i found this website. Its amazing.